# Name of the current, active screen in lightswitch html client

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Is it possible to determine the name of the current, active screen in VS lightswitch html client? Looking at msls.screen and can see .getName, but can't get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried this.Details.Name?

Comment: @user3603308 Did my proposed answer help to provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML Client, you've the option of using the following two properties directly off the screen instance:

```
screen.details._modelId
screen.details.displayName
```

For example in a screen's created event you could do the following:

```
myapp.BrowseScreen.created = function (screen) {
    alert("_modelId [" + screen.details._modelId + "] displayName [" + screen.details.displayName + "]");
};
```

Also, if you need to query the jQuery mobile page id, you can use the following:

```
$.mobile.activePage[0].id
```